# itext for pdf: how to output <pre> code snippet</pre>

Tags: pdf, itext

The line prints to the next line automatically for a paragaph.  How to keep the pre-formated as it is like

```
 line 1
 line 2
 line 3
```

I tried to find the answer from Paragraph class, no luck.

Could some one help?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets see how [HTMLWorker](http://itext.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/itext/trunk/src/core/com/itextpdf/text/html/simpleparser/HTMLWorker.java?revision=4617&view=markup) handles "pre"...  It sets the face to Courier, and sets an "isPre" flag.

In `text(String str)`, HTMLWorker will do some filtering on newlines, spaces, tabs, and so forth... UNLESS isPre is set, in which case 'str' is passed directly into a chunk and added to the current paragraph.

So it looks like you just need to preserver your spaces, "\n"s, and so forth when parsing your input.

`new chunk( "foo\n\n  bar\n  baz\n  qux" )` should appear as:

```
foo

  bar
  baz
  qux
```

PS: Your question wasn't all that clear, so it's quite possible that I'm answering something other than what you asked.  Can't go wrong with sample code.

Answer (score 0):

a html file contains `<pre>` tag and you wish to preserve its format in pdf format.
Try

```
String fileAsOneBigStr = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File    
("aFileName"), "UTF-8"); //FileUtils comes from import 
                         //org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;  
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)<pre>(.*)</pre>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(fileAsOneBigStr);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    String line = m.group(1) + "<br/>";
    m.appendReplacement(sb, line);
}
m.appendTail(sb);
String strToBePassedToITextPdf = sb.toString();
```

Hope this help.  If you find a better solution please let me know (simsamsara3@gmail.com)